# AutoCAD & Excel Connection

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I have spent more than 3 hours searching for a way to connect Excel & AutoCAD Using VBA.

I have found some Sample Codes but it cant Detect the running excel File instead it creates new excel session.

```
Sub excel_con()

Dim excelApp As Object
Dim wbkObj As Object
Dim shtObj As Object

 'make sure Excel reference is set!!
 Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 If Err <> 0 Then
 MsgBox "Could not start Excel", vbExclamation
 End
 End If
 End If
 excelApp.Visible = True
 Set wbkObj = excelApp.Workbooks.Add
 Set shtObj = excelApp.Worksheets(1)
End Sub
```

**This Excel is already running when I run the code**
[image]

**New Excel Session is opened Book6 refers to how many times i ran the code 6 times**
[image]

Comment: Via `excelApp.Workbooks.Add` you create a new workbook. Try `excelApp.ActiveWorkbook` to get the active one (see also [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activeworkbook))

Comment: @Shrotter Not Working

Comment: Are multiple Excel sessions running (e.g. process explorer)? Have you executed your macro step by step to check if a running session is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are allways creating a new workbok

Set wbkObj =
excelApp.Workbooks.Add

2. Every new workbok is created in a new Excel instace.
3. It is not possible, with the code you have, to know if an existent
   or a new excel  instance is being used, unless you debug it step by
   step.

Try this code below, to see what you get and to move on from there.

```
Sub get_excel()

Dim excelApp As Object
'make sure Excel reference is set!!
Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Could not get any valid Excel objet", vbExclamation
else
    excelApp.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```